# Does adding a new object in a has_one relationship, not update the association?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models, an example:

```
class Report ...
  belongs_to :answer_sheet
end

class AnswerSheet ...
  has_one :report
end
```

When I do a:

```
@answersheet.report = Report.create(:data => 'bleah')
@answersheet.save

# and then create another report and assign it to the same @answersheet
# assuming at this stage @answersheet is already reloaded

@answersheet.report = Report.create(:data => 'new data')
@answersheet.save


# (irb) @answersheet.report returns the first report with the data 'bleah' and not
# the one with the new data.
```

Is this supposed to be the correct behavior?

If I want to update the association to the later report, how should I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

It took me a few tries to see what you were talking about. But I got it now.

Take a look at the SQL and you'll find ActiveRecord is doing a select and then adding `ASC` and `LIMIT 1`. There *can* be more than one report records that refer to the same answer_sheet.

You can prevent this situation by adding a validation that checks for uniqueness of answer_sheet_id.

You should also start using save! and create! (note the bang operators) so exceptions are thrown during validation.

Lastly, calling Report.create followed by @answersheet.save performs two database transactions, whereas Report.new followed by @answersheet.save would perform just one.